# Is there a test of pair-wise independence for a sequence of non-identical Bernoulli random variables?

Tags: hypothesis-testing, independence, bernoulli-distribution

Given a sequence of $n$ instances of Bernoulli random variables $x_1,\ldots,x_n$, I am interested in testing whether $x_i$ is independent of $x_{i-1}$ for $i=2,\ldots,n$ (i.e. $p(x_i=0~|~x_{i-1})=p(x_i=0)$).  Unfortunately, unlike the scenario in, say, [this question](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/20563/is-there-a-test-for-independence-in-a-bernoulli-process), $x_i$'s are NOT drawn from an identical Bernoulli distribution--that is, the probability of success $p_i$ may be different from for each $i$.  Does such test exist?  What if we assume only a small drift in $p_i$'s (i.e. $p_{i+1}=p_i+\delta$ where $\delta\approx 0$)?