# How do you test for independence of a process?

Tags: hypothesis-testing, mathematical-statistics, independence

I'm working on a research project for one of my professors. He wants to know whether a variable that takes on different values over a large period of time (say 1,000,000 different values)  is i.i.d. and would like me to design an independence test for it.

I've been learning about independence tests such as Chi-square, McNemar and seen a bunch of research papers floating around about specific cases, but none seem to fit this case. The thing I'm most hung up on is that with all the examples I see, you test one variable against another. I suppose I could assume that all 1,000,000 instances of this variable are different random variables and construct a test that way, but I assume there has to be a better way.

I'd appreciate if you can point me in the right direction and recommend some good textbooks/other reference materials I can refer to! Thanks.

Comment: Can be that you don't need an Independence test, but rather a change-of-point test for your time-distributed variable.

Comment: With a simple expedient, you don't need to design any tests (which is a fraught and huge subject: read Knuth's *Art of Computer Programming* for the details).  Instead, you can capitalize on what the experts have learned simply by applying an empirical probability integral transform to create a series of *uniformly* distributed values and running a standard test of a pseudorandom number generator, such as the Diehard suite.

Comment: Start out with some simpler methods, plotting, compute the autocorrelation function, ...

Answer (score 0):

Here is some 'low-hanging fruit' where auto-correlation
plots and perhaps a runs test reveal marked lack of IID behavior
of a sequence. (See @kjetilbhalvorsen's Comment.)

Data from the late 1970s show that eruptions of Old
Faithful geyser in Yellowstone National Park were of
short (0) or long (1) duration (less or more than 3 min
in length) approximately according to a 2-state
Markov chain--with no occurrences of two short eruptions
in a row. Over the long run, the proportion of long eruptions is about 69%. The R code below simulates 2000 eruptions `x`
according to this Markov chain.

```
set.seed(2020)
m = 2000;  n = 1:m;  x = numeric(n);  x[1]=0
a = 1;  b = 0.44
for (i in 2:m) {
  if (x[i-1]==0) x[i] = rbinom(1,1,a)
  else           x[i] = rbinom(1,1,1-b)
  }
mean(x==1)
[1] 0.7005
```

By contrast, the sequence `y` has 2000 independent
Bernoulli observations with success probability $p=0.7.$

```
set.seed(809)
y = rbinom(2000, 1, .7)
```

ACF plots show significant autocorrelations with lags 2, 3 and 4 (outside the dotted bounds) for the Old Faithful chain (left). The Markov dependence "decays" after a few steps.

By contrast, there are no significant autocorrelations for the IID Bernoulli observations.

[image]

```
par(mfrow=c(1,2))
 acf(x, main="Old Faithful")
 acf(y, main="Bernoulli")
par(mfrow=c(1,1))
```

Here is a link to a recent discussion of [runs tests](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/481814/analyzing-the-statistical-independence-of-a-bernouli-sequence/482012#482012)
on this site.

*Note:* The ACF plot for lengths of Old Faithful eruptions is similar to one in Suess (2010) p146, Springer.